# nomencl formatting issue. How to have the description right aligned?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, nomenclature

I'm using Nomencl package and is working fine. What I do not know how to do is to have the description part starting from the right margin of the page and the symbol part starting from the left margin.
This is what I've got so far:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{ecsthesis}      % Use the Thesis Style
\graphicspath{{../Figures/}}   % Location of your graphics files
\usepackage[sort &compress]{natbib}  % Use Natbib style for the refs.\part{title}
\usepackage[noprefix]{nomencl}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\usepackage{mhchem}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}

 \usepackage{upgreek}
 \usepackage{epigraph}
 \usepackage{tipa}
 \usepackage{array}

   \setlength\epigraphwidth{8cm}
      \setlength\epigraphrule{0pt}
     \renewcommand{\nomname}{List of Symbols}
    \setlength{\nomlabelwidth}{1\hsize}  
 \renewcommand{\nomlabel}[1]{#1 \dotfill}
 \setlength{\nomitemsep}{-\parsep}   
 \makenomenclature
 \begin{document}

 Hello world
 \tableofcontents
\printnomenclature
\chapter{Hello}
Hello
\chapter{World}
 World
    \nomenclature{OECD}{Organisation for Economic Co-operation and Development}
\nomenclature{EIA}{Energy Information Administration}
\nomenclature{GHGs}{Green House Gases}
\nomenclature{BRE}{Building Research Establishment}
\nomenclature{HVAC}{Heating Ventilation Air Conditioning}
\nomenclature[Q]{$ \dot{Q} $}{Heat Transfer Rate}
\nomenclature[k]{$ k $}{Thermal Conductivity }
\nomenclature[A]{$ A $}{Area of Heat Exchange}


  \end{document}
```

I would like to have something more similar to the TOC(with dot in the middle).
Thanks,
M.

Comment: And what if a description is long enough to span two or more lines? How should such entry be formatted?

Comment: Luckily none of them should be that long. In that case ,anyway, would be better to put a maximum length for the description after which it start from a new line, always aligned from the right. But honestly I do not know if it possible :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as your descriptions are not too long this will do the job:

1. Make a copy of the file `nomencl.ist`; call it `mynomencl.ist` and save it in your current working directory. At the end of `mynomencl.ist` add the line

   ```
   item_0 ""
   ```

   save the changes.
2. In your document:

   ```
   \documentclass[twoside]{book}
   \usepackage[noprefix]{nomencl}
   \usepackage{longtable}
   \usepackage{hyperref}
   \usepackage{cleveref}

   \makeatletter
   \def\@@@nomenclature[#1]#2#3{%
   \def\@tempa{#2}\def\@tempb{#3}%
   \protected@write\@nomenclaturefile{}%
   {\string\nomenclatureentry{#1\nom@verb\@tempa @{\nom@verb\@tempa}\protect\dotfill%
   \begingroup\nom@verb\@tempb\protect\nomeqref{\theequation}%
   |nompageref}{\thepage}}%
   \endgroup
   \@esphack}
   \def\thenomenclature{%
   \setlength\parindent{0pt}%
   \@ifundefined{chapter}{\section*}{\chapter*}{\nomname}%
   \nompreamble
   }
   \def\endthenomenclature{\nompostamble}
   \renewcommand\nomentryend{\par}
   \makeatother

   \renewcommand{\nomname}{List of Symbols}

   \makenomenclature

   \begin{document}

    Hello world
   \printnomenclature
   \chapter{Hello}
   Hello
   \chapter{World}
    World
   \nomenclature{OECD}{Organisation for Economic Co-operation and Development}
   \nomenclature{EIA}{Energy Information Administration}
   \nomenclature{GHGs}{Green House Gases}
   \nomenclature{BRE}{Building Research Establishment}
   \nomenclature{HVAC}{Heating Ventilation Air Conditioning}
   \nomenclature[Q]{$ \dot{Q} $}{Heat Transfer Rate}
   \nomenclature[k]{$ k $}{Thermal Conductivity}
   \nomenclature[A]{$ A $}{Area of Heat Exchange}

   \end{document}
   ```
3. Process the document using

   ```
   pdflatex name
   makeindex name.nlo -s mynomencl.ist -o name.nls
   pdflatex name
   pdflatex name
   ```

Here's the resulting list with your example code:

[image]

Comment: looks great but I do not know where to find the .ist file. I download the package using Miktex. (I'm a noob, i know :(_

Comment: FOund! I'll give it a go!

Comment: @user36829 I don't use Windows, but the file is in your system. You can run in a terminal `kpsewhich nomencl.ist` to find the location of the file. Let me know if you can't find it.

Comment: Hi Gonzalo, I tried to run the code as you wrote, an is working. But if I try with a bigger code (my thesis) where the \nomenclature are included in each chapter I have more than one symbols+definition each line. It is the same even if I put the \nomenclature in the same position as the example... I don't know how to add the code in the comment otherwise I'd post it.

Comment: @user36829 comments are not the best place to add code (the formatting is awful). You can add the code to your question as an edit. In the meantime.

Comment: @user36829 add `\renewcommand\nomentryend{\par}`; this should solve the issue. Otherwise, edit your question and add the problematic example there.

Comment: @user36829 You're welcome! Don't forget to mark the answer as accepted by clicking the checkamrk to its left. In case of doubt, please see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852/3954).

Comment: @user36829 After seeing the result, I hope you'll avoid this typographical horror.

Comment: What do you mean as typographical horror? honestly I haven't ask for a style advice, but for a coding advice...

Comment: @MicheleCarboni I don't know if user egreg will be notified of your reply to his comment; usually you need to reply using `@<user>` (as in @egreg) so that the user gets notified.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Ah ok, thx!